# How to change the text of a JavaFX label via the label's ID?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, label

How do I change the text of a JavaFX label only via the ID?
A simplified version of the code is shown below.

For context, we have a grid (GridPane) of labels (it's a sudoku game), the labels are numbered from Label_0_0, ..., to Label_8_8 (indicating the location in the grid). We are going over the label grid in a nested for loop and are trying to set different numbers at different lables/grid-boxes using the ID at the current coordinates of the for loop.
(For simplicity, I omitted the for loop etc. in the code example.)

I've searched the entire internet for answers and haven't figured it out yet, any help is highly appreciated :)

```
String labelID = "ID_1";
int index = 5;

Label currentlySelectedLabel = (Label) ???; // sth like xx.getElementByID, if that existed
currentlySelectedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(index));
```

Some reference to the labels in the FXML:

```
...
            <Label fx:id="Label_8_6" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#MyFrstLabelClicked" onMouseMoved="#OnMouseMovedOnLabel" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label fx:id="Label_8_7" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#MyFrstLabelClicked" onMouseMoved="#OnMouseMovedOnLabel" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label fx:id="Label_8_8" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#MyFrstLabelClicked" onMouseMoved="#OnMouseMovedOnLabel" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "ID"? The CSS ID? Don't you have references to the labels?

Comment: Several approaches are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69429420/230513).

Answer (score 2):

**Preferred approach: use a reference not a lookup**

A preferred approach would be to store a reference to the nodes and use the stored reference.  That way you don't lose all of the goodness of strong typing, compile-time checks, and IDE intelligent editing assistance.

For an example of a preferred approach see:

- [JavaFX: Update ImageView on GridPane click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69429420/javafx-update-imageview-on-gridpane-click)

Additionally, more substantial projects may benefit from a MVC approach so that updates made to the model are automatically reflected in the nodes (and vice-versa):

- [MVC in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/)
- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

**Performing a lookup**

You can find a node by CSS ID via a [node lookup call on a node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup(java.lang.String)) or a [node lookup call on a scene](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#lookup(java.lang.String)).

For example:

```
Label lookedupLabel = (Label) scene.lookup("#myId");
```

The call takes a CSS selector to find a matching node.

> Finds this Node, or the first sub-node, based on the given CSS selector. If this node is a Parent, then this function will traverse down into the branch until it finds a match. If more than one sub-node matches the specified selector, this function returns the first of them.

This approach assumes that an ID has already been set on the node by calling [setId](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setId(java.lang.String)):

```
node.setId("myId");
```

Or in FXML when the node is defined you can set an `fx:id` attribute:

```
fx:id="myId"
```

or an `id` attribute:

```
id="myId"
```

Either will work, but only setting the `fx:id` is usually more convenient as it will also set the corresponding `@FXML` reference value in the controller, in addition to the CSS id.

**Generating a layout pass**

For the lookup to function, you may need to perform a layout pass, by calling:

```
parentNode.applyCss();
parentNode.layout();
```

Perform a layout pass before a CSS lookup if:

1. you have modified the scene graph in the current pulse, OR
2. you are trying to find a node that will dynamically be created by the skin of a control, OR
3. you want to find the dimensions of a node you look up.

If the layout pass is not performed, the looked-up node might not be found or may report the incorrect attribute values.

For more information on layout passes see:

- [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass)