# How do I get X and Y Coordinates of different rows and columns in a gridpane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, game-development, gridpane

I'm currently making a game board and want to be able to move pieces from one tile to another. I'm trying to do this by getting the centerX and centerY of each tile as the user click on it, which would then allow me to move my pieces based off of those values.

Here is what I tried:

```
gameBoard.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        Node target = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();

        if (target != gameBoard) {
            Bounds bounds = target.getBoundsInParent();
            System.out.println("bounds = " + bounds);
            System.out.println("centerX = " + (bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth()/2));
            System.out.println("centerY = " + (bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()/2));
        }
});
```

However `centerX =`  and `centerY =`  only print out `25.0`, no matter the grid row/column I click on. Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but it’s usually cleaner to code this with an event handler for each of the pieces, instead of a single event handler for the board. That way your event handler already has access to information like which piece was clicked, what its location is, etc.

Comment: Two approaches are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69429741/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I think this helped I'm able to get the rows and columns of the circles in the Grid.

Comment: @RyanCruz: Excellent; you should update your question to reflect the the revised approach; going forward, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); if not, I can close as a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by `target.getBoundsInParent()` this gives you the clicked element bounds in relation to its parent.

The reason  why you got the

> centerX = 25.0

and

> centerY = 25.0

for all the cells is because, if your grid cells are uniform, clicking any cells will give you same dimension and its relative position with its parent.

try to convert the local coordinates to your scene coordinates.

```
gameBoard.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
    Node target = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();

    if (target != gameBoard) {
        Bounds bounds = target.getBoundsInParent();
        Point2D pointInScene = target.localToScene(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2, bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2);

        System.out.println("bounds = " + bounds);
        System.out.println("centerX in Scene = " + pointInScene.getX());
        System.out.println("centerY in Scene = " + pointInScene.getY());
    }
});
```