# GridPane indexing problems

Tags: javafx

I have problem getting correct index of a specific cell on a GridPane.
Here is the code snippet:

```
public void canEat(VBox cell) {
        int nextRowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(cell) - 1;
        int currentColumnIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(cell);
        // -1 is placeholder for imposible move
        int plusColIndex = -1;
        int minusColIndex = -1;
        if(currentColumnIndex != 0) {
            minusColIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(cell) - 1;
        }
        if(currentColumnIndex != 7) {
            plusColIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(cell) + 1;
        }
        if(plusColIndex != -1) {
System.out.println("Current col: " + currentColumnIndex);
            System.out.println("Cell col: " + (GridPane.getColumnIndex(cell)) + " Cell row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(cell));
            System.out.println("NEXT col: " + plusColIndex + " next row: " + nextRowIndex);
            VBox eat = (VBox) myGrid.getChildren().get(nextRowIndex * 8 + plusColIndex + 1);
            System.out.println("eat col: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(eat) + " eat row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(eat));
}
```

So for this code if I run it on lets say this kind of grid:

```
(0,0)   (0,1)   (0,2)   (0,3)   (0,4)   (0,5)   (0,6)   (0,7)
(1,0)   (1,1)   (1,2)   (1,3)   (1,4)   (1,5)   (1,6)   (1,7)
(2,0)   (2,1)   (2,2)   (2,3)   (2,4)   (2,5)   (2,6)   (2,7)...
```

if I am placed at the cell (2, 0) and I run this method I get following output:

```
Current col: 0
Cell col: 0 Cell row: 2
NEXT col: 1 next row: 1
eat col: 1 eat row: 1
```

Which is good, but my question is how come that I had "System.out.println("NEXT col: " + plusColIndex + " next row: " + nextRowIndex);" print the same as when I used "System.out.println("eat col: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(eat) + " eat row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(eat));" while eat was being created with: " VBox eat = (VBox) myGrid.getChildren().get(nextRowIndex * 8 + plusColIndex + 1);" (notice this **+1**)?
**NOTE:** if I did not put "+1" and had a formula like: "VBox eat = (VBox) myGrid.getChildren().get(nextRowIndex * 8 + plusColIndex)" the output would be: "eat col: 0 eat row: 1".

Any reasonable explanation or explanation on why and what could lead this method to behave like this would be helpful. I'm am using IntelliJ idea, java jdk 21. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
So I just relised taht my problem lies when I add VBox to grid pane cells and then if I print them I need to get "(0,0), (0,1),...", but instead I get "(idk) (0,0),...". As requested from James here is a minimal reproducible example:
fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane fx:id="tabla" gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" fx:controller="com.example.test.HelloController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

HelloApplication.js:

```
package com.example.test;

//imports

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

ControlerApplication.js:

```
package com.example.test;

//imports

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private GridPane tabla;

    public void initTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                VBox cell = new VBox();
                GridPane.setRowIndex(cell, i);
                GridPane.setColumnIndex(cell, j);
                tabla.getChildren().add(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        initTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Node start = tabla.getChildren().get(i * 3 + j);
                Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(start);
                Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(start);

                if (rowIndex != null && colIndex != null) {
                    System.out.print("(" + rowIndex + "," + colIndex + ") ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("(idk) ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this I get:

```
(idk) (0,0) (0,1) 
(0,2) (1,0) (1,1) 
(1,2) (2,0) (2,1)
```

Question is why is at position 0 there a (idk)? I think that this messes my original code and therefore my cells have indexes that I did not expect.

Comment: For reference, several related examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69429420/230513).

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee at all that the child nodes of a grid pane are in the order your question assumes (which I think is one child node per cell, filling by row left to right and then moving top to bottom from row to row). Cells can have multiple child nodes, cells can be empty, child nodes can be unassigned to cells, and the order of nodes in the `getChildren()` list is just the order in which you insert them via something like `getChildren().add(...)`. Without knowing how you added the nodes to the grid, and everything else you did with the grid, the question is unaswerable.

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: Generally, though, this doesn't seem the right way to structure your application. The relationships between the positions should be part of the application state (model); you should not be trying to calculate those things based on the UI classes (view).

Comment: @James_D just edited it explaining how I added it, and it appears something there causes an error

Comment: Create and post a [mre] if you really want to know what is going on. No-one can help you debug this without being able to reproduce it. As I said, though, this simply isn't the right approach. The relationships between these entities are *application state*: you should not rely on storing them in the UI objects.

Comment: @James_D done. Okay so I should've made 2D matrix and connect it with grid pane, and work with matrix right? Well I thought about that but I thought it would waste unnececary memory so I tried it this way. Now it is kind of late, besides I would like to see why this is being printed and why does this happen with this code.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you make grid lines visible the `GridPane` internally adds a `Path` as a child node to display the grid lines. Turn the grid lines off and see if it changes the indexing. Grid lines are recommended (by the API docs) for debugging purposes only.

Comment: *"I should've made 2D matrix and connect it with grid pane"* Yes, basically something along those lines. For a game or simulation (or any UI application, but those seem to be more applicable here) it's always a good plan to first write it from the data perspective only, so you can drive it just from code, and then to add the UI on top of that once it's working. The memory consumed by the data representation is basically negligible compared to the memory consumed by the UI, so that should not be a concern.

Comment: @James_D thank you so much, the problem was in fact that grid lines were turned on(I thought it is just an aesthetic feature) and that somehow for some reason messes indexes of cells. So from: "If I remember correctly, if you make grid lines visible the GridPane internally adds a Path as a child node to display the grid lines." does that mean the output I recived as "(idk)"was basically related to the path to those added lines?

Comment: Also I see your answers everywhere so you helped me already and since you seem so passionate about java, do you have any resource that specifically you would recommend that can help me improve?

Comment: @asd It is kind of off-topic, but in what way do you want to improve?  The question is rhetorical, you can answer it yourself, you don't need to answer it here.  Be very specific.  Just wishing to improve in general is not a goal, it is only a wish.  Setting realistic goals (the smaller and more focused the better) and working to achieve them (repetition with small changes and challenges each time) with passion and motivation is what allows you to improve.  It helps if you have fun doing it, so do that.

Comment: The fact that the correct operation of your code depends on something that should be irrelevant (turning on/off the grid lines), is a red flag that your approach is fundamentally flawed. You should not be relying on some internal implementation of a library for correct operation of your code.